# are batch files NOT executable unlike shell scripts?

Tags: c++, windows, boost, process, win32-process

I am using `boost.process` to run an external process with some given input. user can specify that external process. So most of the time user specifies a shell script or batch script.

I am simply doing `boost::process::launch(_script, arguments, context);` which works both real executables as well as shell scripts as long as they are executable (+x) as expected. but when I run it in windows. it doesn't work If I pass a batch file in `_script` however it works if I specify a real executable.

This makes me think that in Windows batch scripts are NOT executables at all ? They are just interpreted through cmd.exe ! is this true ?

I can launch `cmd.exe` and specify `/c _script argv` as command line parameters. but that will not be cross platform.

and I don't want to make `system()` calls because I'll not have full control on created processes ?

Comment: Shell scripts are executable?

Comment: at least I can launch them through `boost::process::launch`

Comment: @MartinJames: kind of. `#!` is a 16 bit magic number that tells the kernel "when this file is executed, run the following program passing it the name of this file as an argument". The program of course happens to be an interpreter for the script, in this case the shell. On Windows, batch files contain no such trickery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right, batch files are not directly executable and require a command processor to run them.

That said, solving the portability issue should be fairly straightforward, and can be done either at compile-time (via preprocessor macros) or run-time (Windows-specific environment variables? script filename extension?)

I'd probably go with the former as more robust.

Comment: a nice way to factor out system dependencies is to have different headers for different systems, chosen by the include path set up for the compiler. using preprocessor macros generally creates a mess. to wit, the mess one observes in just about any code base

Comment: Its not even guaranteed that all executables in windows will be batch scripts. So Its safer to check for `.bat` in extension.

Comment: @NeelBasu: Bear in mind that `cmd /c` will work correctly both with executables and with batch files.

Comment: but wouldn't it create a `cmd` window ? actually I need to run the executable several 100 times in a row. So it should never pop up with 100 windows

Comment: @NeelBasu: if using the Win32 API, you would solve this by passing the CREATE_NO_WINDOW flag.  Boost presumably has an equivalent, or a way of passing the flag through.